# Make @GeneratedValue start a sequence with a specific value

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I have a class that is an entity of a table from a PostgreSQL database:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter private Long id;
...
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE,
...
```

When the application starts, this table fills with some test data (from .sql file trough "INSERT INTO..."). However, when a new instance is created in the database trough Hibernate, the ID always starts with **one**, forcing me to create it multiple times until generated ID reaches the required value.

I need the ID counter to start with a number, that is **one more than the ID of the previous record in the table**. Ideally not requiring me to manually specify the ID value.

Comment: you could use @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)

Comment: @vaibhavsahu but I have to specify the value for a sequence manually, and do so for every entity I have. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "mySequence")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence")
    @Getter private Long id;
```

And then in your .sql file write insert queries like this:

```
INSERT INTO users values (select nextval('mySequence'), ...
```

> select nextval('mySequence')

will give you next available value from sequence table

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "your_custom_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="your_custom_sequence", sequenceName = "MY_CUSTOM_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
```

and you can define your sequence in sql like                                `CREATE SEQUENCE MY_CUSTOM_SEQ MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20 NOMAXVALUE;`

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible to make the value from which the sequence begins being set automatically depending on the number of previous records?

Comment: In Oracle you could update a sequence in the database manually if you are on development database with this:

SELECT FOOBAR_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;
ALTER SEQUENCE FOOBAR_SEQ INCREMENT BY 500;
 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_2011.htm

Comment: @ErionOmeri Thanks, for Oracle database this would be a great way to solve this issue!